# Shouldn't we say "keep quietness" instead of "keep quiet"?

Tags: difference, adverbs

I feel that **keep quiet** sounds a bit weird. We are ordering to maintain silence. So we ask for the state of silence, we should say **keep quietness** because it is the state we require here. We could use **be quiet** instead because here no state is required.

A few examples-
Keep playing (a state), keep doing, keep working, etc. We don't say keep play.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that

> quietness (noun)

is the state of little to no noise, so one might say

> The *quietness* was broken by the laughter of children.

However,

> keep quiet
>   be quiet
>   stay quiet

are imperatives telling someone how to act (verb) and not make any noise.

> keep quiet
>   keep still
>   keep your hands to yourself

are all idioms which is what might be confusing you since nothing is specifically "kept".

These are regularly used terms, especially with children.

Comment: The problem I think in their misunderstanding is the word "keep". In a sense "keep quiet" means "maintain quiet". I think the problem is "keep quiet" is incorrect and short for "keep it quiet".

Comment: Why do you think "[keep quiet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/lowres.cartoonstock.com/animals-cats-pet-animal_rights-animal_rights_protestors-protests-grin406_low.jpg)" is incorrect?